# How do I pass an ID parameter to a show method when writing a test for a Rails controller method?

Tags: parameters, controller, ruby-on-rails-5, show, minitest

I"m using Rails 5.  I have the following method in my controller

```
class LinesController < ApplicationController

    ...

  def show
    @line = Line.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Using minitest, I would like to test this method, so I have written this as my test ...

```
  test "get show page with valid line id" do
    test_line_id = 1
    get line_url, params: {id: test_line_id}
    line = assigns(:line)
    assert_equal test_line_id, line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

But when I run the test I'm getting the below error ....

```
Error:
LinesControllerTest#test_get_show_page_with_valid_line_id:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lines"} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/lines_controller_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:LinesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/lines_controller_test.rb:14
```

Why is the error complaining about an ID when I'm passing an ID as a parameter?

**Edit:** What rake routes returns

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                         Controller#Action
       rails_settings_ui          /settings                           RailsSettingsUi::Engine
        new_user_session GET      /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST     /users/sign_in(.:format)            devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE   /users/sign_out(.:format)           devise/sessions#destroy
       new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)       devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)      devise/passwords#edit
           user_password PATCH    /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
                         PUT      /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#update
                         POST     /users/password(.:format)           devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_registration GET      /users/cancel(.:format)             devise/registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET      /users/sign_up(.:format)            devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET      /users/edit(.:format)               devise/registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH    /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#update
                         PUT      /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE   /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#destroy
                         POST     /users(.:format)                    devise/registrations#create
                    page GET      /pages/:page_name(.:format)         pages#show
                   lines GET      /lines(.:format)                    lines#index
                    line GET      /lines/:id(.:format)                lines#show
               get_stops GET|POST /lines/:line_id/get_stops(.:format) lines#get_stops
                    stop GET      /stops/:stop_id(.:format)           stops#show
                  search GET      /search(.:format)                   pages#search
               favorites GET      /favorites(.:format)                favorites#index
                favorite GET      /favorite/:stop_id(.:format)        favorites#new
              unfavorite GET      /unfavorite/:stop_id(.:format)      favorites#delete
                  issues GET      /issues(.:format)                   issues#index
                         POST     /issues(.:format)                   issues#create
               new_issue GET      /issues/new(.:format)               issues#new
              edit_issue GET      /issues/:id/edit(.:format)          issues#edit
                   issue GET      /issues/:id(.:format)               issues#show
                         PATCH    /issues/:id(.:format)               issues#update
                         PUT      /issues/:id(.:format)               issues#update
                         DELETE   /issues/:id(.:format)               issues#destroy
                    root GET      /                                   pages#dashboard
```

**Edit 2:** In response to the answer given, I changed my method to

```
  test "get show page with valid line id" do
    param_line = lines(:one)
    assert_not_nil param_line

    puts "id: #{param_line.id}"
    get line_path, id: param_line.id
    line = assigns(:line)
    assert_equal param_line.id, line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
```

and got this error upon running the test

```
# Running:

...id: 1
E

Error:
LinesControllerTest#test_get_show_page_with_valid_line_id:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lines"} missing required keys: [:id]
    test/controllers/lines_controller_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:LinesControllerTest>'


bin/rails test test/controllers/lines_controller_test.rb:16
```

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like and what does `rake routes` return? I don't think this related to the parameter you are passing, it is related to how you are calling the route.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include the "rake routes" output.

Comment: Is there a reason you use line_url instead of line_path? Usually you only need to use the absolute path (line_url), if you're outside of your application (e.g. in emails). Probably has nothing to do with your problem – just curious.

Comment: I believe @morgler is correct. You take the route name output from the `rake routes` return and append it with `_path` not `_url`. You can also do something like `get '/lines/:id(.:format)` and hit the end point explicitly.

Comment: Hey maybe its that simple!  I'll give morgler's answer a go and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems it should simply be

```
get line_path(test_line_id)
```

in your test.

Explanation:
No need to wrap this in `params`. `params` is just the internal hash Rails provides to your controller action to read the parameters passed in with the request. And the first argument you pass to a path generator will always be mapped to `id` in params.

So your code would pass in `params[:params]` – and since we have strong params, the `params[:params]` parameter will be filter out (you should see a warning about this in your logs).

Also, as I already commented above and @NicholasMartinez pointed out, you should use `_path` instead of `_url`, unless you explicitly need an absolute path (like in links used outside of your application, e.g. in emails).

Comment: I believe your `get line_url` is incorrect. In your comment above you mention it should be `get line_path` which is correct.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasMartinez for pointing this out! Updated my answer.

Comment: @morgler, I gave your answer a go (pretty sure I've done what you asked).  I included the test and the error in the question.  The error was "ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lines"} missing required keys: [:id]".  That "puts" statement returns "1" -- thought perhaps there was no ID for that object but it does seem like there's an ID.

Comment: Sorry for my overly complicated code. Of course this should be written as `get line_path(test_line_id)`. I was too tired – I will fix it in the answer ;). Does it fix your problem?

Comment: It did!  Thank you!!